# Deployment Symfony 2.4 on Microsoft Azure (git/composer)

Tags: symfony, azure, composer-php, icu, intl

For the last two days I'm trying to push my application on Azure but I'm facing problems about the Symfony 2.4 deps (with composer). The main error is :

> symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

I saw on the internet that the problem could be about the php_intl extension not loaded. So after hours I managed to get it by creating a bin\ext\php_intl.dll in my root directory (the documentation does not mention the ext subdirectory, and it was not working for me when I put the intl into the bin directory).

- Internationalization support **enabled**
- version **1.1.0**
- ICU version **49.1.2**
- ICU Data version **49.1.2**

But I always get the same error. Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your composer.json :

```
require: {
   "symfony/icu": "1.1.*"
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html, chapter "ICU and Deployment Problems"

Comment: Weird because it works on my local machine, but on Azure, the build_azure.sh gives me: The requested package symfony/icu could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: With 1.1.1, same. symfony/icu v1.1.1 requires lib-icu >=3.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

Will try with 1.2.*